# how to make UIView and button and textfield customly in iphone

Tags: iphone

i need to make a UIView in which i need to make some textfield and button in iphone customly. please help me.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more detail than that. What do you want the end result to be. Add more detail, and this will likely get answered quickly.

Comment: This is a homework task.

Comment: actually i neeed to open a UIView on the button click ,in which there will be some text field and labels and button. through which i can enter some values and save the values in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask for the resources to learn iPhone programming. 
There are two approaches to create a view, either using Interface Builder or through programming. 
For Interface Builder- You can refer any iPhone Programming book or blogs like iCode, iphonedevelopment.blogspot will help. 
For programming - http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2009-01-20T06%3A39%3A00-08%3A00&max-results=5
 this should help.